# Use of QML Animations vs. Animation Files

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I wonder, if it is more beneficial to use the abilities of QML for animations, or prefer to use animation files (such as GIF oder MNG) for simple, small-scale animations.

Examples for what I call "simple, small-scale animations" are:

- turning Hourglasses
- those rotating dots, known from video platforms, while loading
- flashing alert symbols
- those "recharging buttons" known from many RPGs used for special attacks

I don't know much about the internals of Qt, so I am unsure, whether I benefit from hardware acceleration, when programming the animations (e.g. image rotation) or not. And if so, whether this hardware acceleration outperforms the display of pre-calculated animations from GIF and MNG.

Greetings and thanks,
-m-

Comment: Have you run into performance issues using either of the approaches? This seems like an unimportant thing to worry about in terms of performance, especially as most of the things you've mentioned are typically the only instance of their kind on the screen at a time.

Comment: I am planning on running on a first-gen Raspberry Pi B, which is not known for being a "performance beast". Therefore I try to consider the performance from the beginning (I am still in the experimentation phase, where I really only have like a hand full of buttons that don't do much...) before I decide what my project will be.  
But if I get you correctly, you state that both should not be like "the performance killers"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't worry about things like this unless they visibly slow the performance of your application. Some points to consider:

- The use cases you mentioned almost always involve only one "busy indicator" being visible at a time.
- Both [`Image`](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtdeclarative.git/tree/src/quick/items/qquickimagebase.cpp#n246) and [`AnimatedImage`](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtdeclarative.git/tree/src/quick/items/qquickanimatedimage.cpp#n315) have the high DPI @*x file look-up.
- Both `Image` and `AnimatedImage` support caching.
- Both `Image` and `AnimatedImage` will use the Qt Quick scene graph to display the images (OpenGL textures, which should result in hardware acceleration).
- `AnimatedImage` has to [read several images](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/gui/image/qmovie.cpp#n399), but won't require rotation.
- Rotation of images is pretty cheap, as far as I know.
- It's trivial to swap out one with the other, or with [something else](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-busyindicator.html).

If you're looking for good general performance advice, read the [Performance Considerations And Suggestions](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-performance.html) documentation.